# Accessing non-final values inside anonymous inner class

Tags: java, android, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

I have these 5 Edittext fields and I want to write these values in database using a button. For button Clicklistener  i've used anonymous inner class but only final values are allowed, that means I will get empty fields while writing in database. How can I access these fields as non-final? Is there any way?

```
 public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    EditText yardarea = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.yardarea);
    String areaofyard = yardarea.getText().toString();
    EditText brick = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.brick);
    final String brickused = brick.getText().toString();
    EditText rcc = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.rcc);
    final String rccused = rcc.getText().toString();
    EditText overhead = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.overhead);
    final String ovhh = overhead.getText().toString();
    EditText underground = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.underground);
    final String ung = underground.getText().toString();

    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.register);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            databaseAccess.open();
            databaseAccess.insertIntoCriteriaTable(areaofyard, brickused, rccused, ovhh, ung );
            databaseAccess.close();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get values from edittext?

Comment: @AbhayBohra yes. i've edited the code slightly. please see it.

Comment: Why don't you declare strings and variables as global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try **this declare EditText  as global**

```
EditText yardarea , brick , rcc,  overhead , underground;

public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    yardarea = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.yardarea);
     brick = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.brick);
    rcc = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.rcc);
    overhead = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.overhead);
    underground = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.underground);

    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.register);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String areaofyard = yardarea.getText().toString();
            String brickused = brick.getText().toString();
            String rccused = rcc.getText().toString();
            String ovhh = overhead.getText().toString();
            String ung = underground.getText().toString();

            DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            databaseAccess.open();
            databaseAccess.insertIntoCriteriaTable(areaofyard, brickused, rccused, ovhh, ung );
            databaseAccess.close();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    final EditText yardarea = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.yardarea);
    final EditText brick = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.brick);
    final EditText rcc = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.rcc);
    final EditText overhead = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.overhead);
    final EditText underground = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.underground);

    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.register);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String areaofyard = yardarea.getText().toString();
            String brickused = brick.getText().toString();
            String rccused = rcc.getText().toString();
            String ovhh = overhead.getText().toString();
            String ung = underground.getText().toString();

            DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            databaseAccess.open();
            databaseAccess.insertIntoCriteriaTable(areaofyard, brickused, rccused, ovhh, ung );
            databaseAccess.close();

        }
    });
}
```

You can just declare the EditText objects as final or you can also declare them as global variables and in onclick of button use the same code posted above.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting getting the string in the onClickListener instead?

> public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle
>   savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
>
> ```
>     EditText yardarea = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.yardarea);
>
>
>
>
>
>     EditText brick = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.brick);
>
>
>
>     EditText rcc = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.rcc);
>
>
>
>     EditText overhead = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.overhead);
>
>
>
>
>     EditText underground = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.underground);
>
>
>
>
>     Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.register);
>     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             String areaofyard = yardarea.getText().toString();
>             String brickused = brick.getText().toString();
>             String rccused = rcc.getText().toString();
>             String ovhh = overhead.getText().toString();
>             String ung = underground.getText().toString();
>             DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
>             databaseAccess.open();
>             databaseAccess.insertIntoCriteriaTable(areaofyard, brickused, rccused, ovhh, ung );
>             databaseAccess.close();
>
>         }
>     });
>
>
>
> }
> ```

Comment: not possible becaues we cannot get the refrence of yardarea inside that inner class.

Answer (score 0):

```
 You should get the value from edittext inside onClick 


 final EditText yardarea = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.yardarea);
 final EditText brick = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.brick);
 final EditText rcc = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.rcc);
 final EditText overhead = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.overhead);
 final EditText underground = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.underground);


 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              String brickused = brick.getText().toString();
              String rccused = rcc.getText().toString();
              String ovhh = overhead.getText().toString();
              String areaofyard = yardarea.getText().toString();
              String ung = underground.getText().toString();                  
              // Do your database operation with these value
            }
        });
```